# Preprocessing a faded image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to preprocess a slightly tilted and faded receipt image.

I found the code to adjust the position of the photo. But I couldn't figure out how to make the texts clear.

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTJ2d.jpg)

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np



img_path = "rec.jpg"

img = cv2.imread(img_path)
cv2.imshow("org",img)

img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imshow("rgb",img_rgb)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - gray
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Compute rotated bounding box
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]

if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
else:
    angle = -angle
print(angle)

# Rotate image to deskew
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)[enter image description here]
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('rotated', rotated)

bit_img = cv2.bitwise_not(rotated)

kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)

dilate_img = cv2.dilate(bit_img,kernel,iterations=1)

cv2.imshow("last",dilate_img)




cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[after preprocess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQio6.png)

Even though I tried various codes with opencv, the accuracy rate did not reach the level I wanted.